# .htaccess redirect multiple domain to single domain

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to have all webpages from an old domain go to the corresponding webpages on a new domain with the same file structure.  I'm using the following code but the problem is the old webpage goes to the index webpage and not the corresponding webpage. Basically the (.*) which I think captures the rest of the url isn't being displayed with the $1 in the rewrite rule?

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com(.*) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `$1`, you'll need to capture something in your RewriteRule using `()`.
Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects `http://olddomain.com/page.php` to `http://www.newdomain.com/page.php`.

Also, in case there can be multiple `olddomain`s, redirect any url that is NOT at `newdomain`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects `http://notnewdomain.com/page.php` to `http://www.newdomain.com/page.php`.

**EDIT:**

Here's a screenshot of my test at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be:
[image: tested at htaccess.madewithlove.be]

Comment: closer but it drops the folder. Example: http://notnewdomain.com/folder/page.php goes to http://newdomain.com/page.php rather than http://newdomain.com/folder/page.php

Comment: It also redirects `http://example.com/folder/page.php` to `http://www.newdomain.com/folder/page.php`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It doesn't drop the folder for me. I have included a screenshot of my test. Try it here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ Remember to restart apache after making changes to your `htaccess` file.